# Pagination fault in custom post type archive page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I create ad custom post type  `register_post_type( 'videos', $args);`
and custom taxonomy for that  `register_taxonomy( 'video_category_categorie', 'videos', $args );` 
**Maximum number of post displayed is 2 per page. Via word press backend**
in **archive-videos. php** i write the for displaying the post from a specific taxonomy ( taxonomy item id is 3  )  `$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;`

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'videos','paged' => $paged,'tax_query' => array(
    array(
    'taxonomy' => 'video_category_categorie',
    'field' => 'term_id',
    'terms' => 3)
));

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
echo get_the_title().'<br>';
endwhile;
twentyfourteen_paging_nav();
```

Now i get the result correctly only pst from taxonomy id 3 is displayed. 
But the pagination is not correct. it  showing 1 2 3 4 . actually there is 5 post that is in taxonomy id 3 . so the correct pagination is 1 2 3 .

And also when clicking  4 page the page didn’t show any post name .

Please help

Comment: If you want only 2 posts per page, you need to tell WP_Query that. Add:

    "posts_per_page" => 2

to your $args array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [the source for `twentyfourteen_paging_nav()`](http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/WordPress/WordPress/source-function-twentyfourteen_paging_nav.html#11-62), you'll see it acts upon the `$GLOBALS['wp_query']`, not on your custom loop query.

If you want to keep using `twentyfourteen_paging_nav()`, you need to use the standard loop, and modify [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Alters_Main_Loop) to alter the global `wp_query` object instead of your `$loop`, which is a separate instance of `WP_Query`.

In your case, that would mean changing the line:

```
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

to:

```
query_posts ( $args );
```

and removing `$loop->` from the rest of your code.

If you can't do that for any reason, you'll need to switch to another [Wordpress pagination function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination)

Comment: can you please look my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28337490/how-to-set-search-and-pagination-based-on-custom-taxonomy-item-in-custom-post-ty